# test for difference between matched pairs in 1:1 matched study

Tags: matching, wilcoxon-signed-rank, observational-study, mcnemar-test, case-control-study

**Background**: I have a retrospective study (registry) that contains data on people with kidney transplant. Among these patients, we have a very small number of people with a specific genetic disease (n=17) and a lot of people without the disease (N=13000). The registry provides data on various outcomes for the patients, such as graft failure, various lab values, infections etc. The theory is that this disease increases the risk of kidney complications and poor transplant outcomes.

**Aims**:
(1) perform 1:1 matching on age, gender, race of cases with the genetic disease with those without the disease.
(2) do a descriptive analysis of the incidence of various outcomes (serum ALT levels, graft failure, HCV infection etc) between the two groups.

**Done so far**: already performed the 1:1 case-control match (i.e., one control for each case) using the guidance in this article (https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi29/173-29.pdf)

**Question**: If I want to do a descriptive analysis (example table below) to evaluate differences between matched pairs (i.e., compare cases with controls) on specific characteristics, what should I use to obtain the statistics and p-value?
Is it ok to use signed ranked test (if variable is continuous) and McNemar test (if categorical)? I’ve read a bunch of articles and it seems like opinions are divided with regards to whether matching should/can be ignored or not though unfortunately I’m not really seasoned enough to fully understand the arguments one way or another and make the best decision. My inclination would be to **not** use any sort of tests for dependent samples since the cases and controls are not really paired observations in my opinion (matching only made them slightly more comparable but it's not really like observations taken from the same subject at different times, or before/after type of observations to warrant using dependent samples tests?). If it’s ok to ignore matching, can I use independent samples t-test and chi square?

Sorry if these questions are ignorant, I don’t have any prior experience with matching case-control or cohort studies but I'm trying to find the best solution (not even sure if the specific situation I have would even qualify as case-control rather than cohort, though I’m leaning to think it’s probably more like cohort).

Thank you in advance for any thoughts/advice!
[image]

Comment: This is a cohort study, not a case-control study. In a case-control study, you have people with the outcome of interest (complications), you find people without complications, and you compare the incidence of the disease between the two. In a cohort study, you have people with the disease, you find people without the disease, and you compare the incidence of the outcome.

Are you aware that 17 pairs of patients is likely way too few to make any meaningful statement about this relationship? Just because it's all the data you have doesn't mean you should analyze it.

Comment: @Noah, thank you for your input. Actually, it's funny you mentioned the small sample size, that was going to be my next question as I completely agree with you that it's probably not sufficient number of people to draw any meaningful conclusions. But just for my own reference, I'm interested in knowing how one might even approach this problem, assuming we didn't have such a small N. What would you use for the descriptive statistics?

Comment: For a cohort study, you should definitely take into account the paired nature of the sample, using the methods you described or others (e.g., paired t-test, cluster-robust standard errors, etc.). If you have exactly matched and you want a conditional estimand, you can also use conditional logistic regression for a binary outcome or stratification in a Cox model.

Comment: Got it, thank you!